# Is my Dell Inspiron 15 laptop A2DP enabled?

Tags: windows-8.1

My laptop is Dell Inspiron 15-3521 laptop with win 8.1. I would like to know if it is A2DP enabled ? How to I find it ?I do not need any Fixes. Its just the tech info I want.

Answer (score 0):

Tech info is on http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/manuals, the second entry is specifications.

Bluetooth is not even mentioned, but the driver support on http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/drivers gives you two driver options: 1703/1705 or 1704.

There is no information other that people with both options have problems connecting. I would take that as a 'no' to your question since there is absolutely no support available, even if the option may be implemented.

A decent USB Bluetooth module with reliable drivers, with A2DP and even apt-X can be had for around $10. I would go this route.